# File access in @onMessage method of @ServerEndPoint class

Tags: java, websocket, osgi-bundle

I have developed a java project that is deployed as an OSGI felix bundle.
This project contains 2 packages: 
- the first package contains just a class (CLASS_1) that should write/read some messages to/from a file;
- the second package contains 2 classes: a webSocketServer (@ServerEndPoint) that contains a method @onMessage (and also  all other mandatory methods) and another class to register the websocket.

In the method @OnMessage, present in the second package, I would call the method present in the first package to store the coming messages.

The websocket works properly if I don't use the method of the CLASS_1. But when I use it, at runtime ( when one message arrives) I have a ClassNotFoundException for that class (CLASS_1). I don't know what is the problem. Maybe something missing in the pom.xml file? (I'm using maven)

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use service-component architecture of OSGi compendium. In your situation, CLASS_1 must publish its service that will be used from your other bundles (via an interface), and you also need to define component classes in order to inject your services and get use of them.

There are various libraries to implement service-component architecture like apache.felix.scr, apache blueprint, aQute etc. I would recommend you to scrutinize each of them and decide which fits your project best.